# Turtle creates an extra screen (unwanted)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I made screen has a canvas, that got some drawings in it. I also made a function that makes a turtle and moves it. The problem is when the turtle is created, it also creates a new window in which the turtle moves. I don't want that second window. Is there a way to move a turtle and make it appear on the canvas without creating a second window?

Here's the function:

```
def Mueve_Carro(type):

    color = StringVar

    if tipoCarro == 1:
        type = "blue"
    elif tipoCarro == 2:
        type = "orange"
    elif tipoCarro == 3:
        type = "brown"

    ball = Turtle()
    ball.penup()
    ball.shape("circle")
    ball.shapesize(1,1,1)
    ball.color(type)
    ball.goto(-60,22)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Turtle()` class you are using will always automatically create a new canvas. You have to use `RawTurtle(canvas)` where that `canvas` variable is the screen you created outside this function (so you also need to pass it as parameter)

So basically

```
def Mueve_Carro(type, canvas):

    #...

    ball = RawTurtle(canvas)

    #...
```

Despite what the name may suggest, there are no other differences between `RawTurtle` and `Turtle` aside from the creation of the canvas.